# macOS Performance - 2.5.1:Your app uses or references the following non-public API

Tags: macos, api, cocoa

**I submit the APP has been rejected several times to Mac AppStore. it is a video application which base on VLCKit, only used the third-party library also is VLCKit. here is the app rejection issue :**

> "Performance - 2.5.1
>
> Your app uses or references the following non-public API(s):
>
> '/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices'
>
> : CGSCreateRegisteredCursorImage
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store as it can
>   lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
>
> Next Steps
>
> If you have defined methods in your source code with the same names as
>   the above-mentioned APIs, we suggest altering your method names so
>   that they no longer collide with Apple's private APIs to avoid your
>   application being flagged in future submissions.
>
> Additionally, one or more of the above-mentioned APIs may reside in a
>   library included with your application. If you do not have access to
>   the library's source, you may be able to search the compiled binary
>   using "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool can
>   output a list of the methods that the library calls and "otool -ov"
>   will output the Objective-C class structures and their defined
>   methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the
>   problematic code resides.
>
> If you are unable to reproduce this issue, ensure you are testing the
>   exact version of the app that you submitted for review, and that
>   you're doing so in a minimally privileged environment. See Technical
>   Q&A QA1778: How to reproduce bugs reported against Mac App Store
>   submissions.
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see
>   Technical Note TN2123 - CrashReporter."

**That made me crazy , according Apple's feedback, I have used "strings","otool -L" and "otool -ov" , but didn't find relevant content. how to solve this problem? please tell me.thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VLC calls `CGSCreateRegisteredCursorImage()` in code used for screen capture.](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/modules/access/screen/mac.c#L217)

You will probably need to remove this functionality from libvlc to make it pass App Store API checks.

More importantly, though, VLC (and libvlc) are licensed under the GPL. Please make sure your application will be compliant with this license before you proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will be compliant with this license before  proceed. and do you know how to modify the libvlc code ?